# Data input for K means clustering with Scipy, Python?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, k-means

I have a point dataset with two attributes and I would like to cluster these points based on the attribute values. I want to use K means clustering but I am unsure on how my input data should look like when using Scipy's implementation.

For example should I make a numpy array with each row containing: FID, attribute 1, attribute 2, x-coord, y-coord, or an array of just the attribute values? The attributes are integers and floats.

Comment: are the x- and y-positions relevant for the clusters? I.e. is the position of the points something you want to consider for the clustering? Or only the attribute values?

Comment: mainly the attribute values, since the point data is already aggregated and I want to cluster regardless of position for sampling purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in your data should be descrete observations and columns should correspond to features or dimensions of your data. For your case: FID, attribute 1, attribute 2, x-coord, y-coord should be on columns and each row should represent observations at different time steps.

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq
nbStates = 4
Centers, _ = kmeans(Data, nbStates)
Data_id, _ = vq(Data, Centers)
```

where Data should be Nx5 matrix where 5 columns should correspond to your 5 features FID, attribute 1, attribute 2, x-coord, y-coord, and N rows corresponding to N observations. In other words reshape your FID data array as column vector and same for other features and horizontally concatenate them and put it as an argument for kmeans function. nbStates represents number of clusters which you expect to see, it should be set up beforehand. What you will get as a result is Centers which is NxM matrix where N corresponds to clusters and M corresponds to number of features in your data. Data_id matrix is a column vector which represents the labels of your data points corresponding to each cluster. It is Nx1 matrix where N is a number of data points.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cluster solely on the attributes you should create a `2xN` matrix (according to the [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans)), with your attributes as columns and each datapoint as row.

You will probably enhance your results by whitening (normalizing) the data points. Assuming your data have two fields `attr1` and `attr2` and you have a list `dataset` containing them the corresponding code whould look like:

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, whiten 

data = np.ndarray((2, len(dataset))
for row, d in enumerate(dataset):
    data[0, row] = d.attr1
    data[1, row] = d.attr2

whitened_data = np.whiten(data)

clusters, _ = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(data, 5)  # 5 is the number of clusters you assume
assignments, _ = vq(data, clusters)
```